# This function declaration is throwing an error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘=’ token

Tags: c, function, default-value

```
#include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
static xmlDocPtr importSettings(char file[]="CsSettings.xml"){}
```

That's not so complicated, why does it always throw this error?

```
test.c:3: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘=’ token
```

Am I compiling it wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C doesn't have default parameter values. You need to compile your file as C++.

**Edit**:

So you don't want to use C++. (Good, because I don't want to use C++, either.) Here's one reasonable way to do the same thing:

```
static xmlDocPtr importSettings(char file*)
{
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        file = "CsSettings.xml";
    }
    /* etc. */
}
```

This way, if you want to use the default, just pass NULL to the import settings.

Another option is to add `#define DEFAULT_XML_FILE "CsSettings.xml"` somewhere in your header, and then require callers to pass `DEFAULT_XML_FILE` if they want to use the default.

Comment: Wouldn't writing the C code right be slightly more reasonable than switching entirely to C++?

Comment: I'd like to hear your option wooble (Don't want to use C++) Is there perhaps a way to make it optional and give it a value inside the actual function? Should I use overrides?

Comment: @Wooble, @JV, added some suggestions for how to implement this pattern in pure C.

Comment: @Wooble, `file == ""` is very likely *not* to work as intended in C.

Comment: indeed, your NULL example is much better.

Answer (score 4):

C doesn't have default values on arguments. [C++ has them](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/77-default-parameters/), though.